# geodjango with mysql getting error django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, django, geodjango

seetings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql','django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql'
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"my.cnf"),
    },
 },
```

}

without 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql' the code is working fine but since i want to use django geolocation using mysql, i added this (if I don't add I get

> 'databaseoperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'

error), and now I am getting

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user ---"
>   error although the user has full privileges.

Please help I am new to django

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you try to set multiple database backends in your settings but you need just one: `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql` works for both spatial and non-spatial use cases.

So your `settings.py` should probably look something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"my.cnf"),
        },
    },
}
```